# How to access first element of a struct in C after looping

Tags: c, structure

In C, I use a for loop to enter the elements of a struct and I enter them successfully. Yet, after I loop for the input, I want to access all the elements that I created by using malloc function from the beginning to print the elements. How can I loop from the first element of the allocated memory after using a loop to create struct elemenets?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Ogrenci{
    
    char isim[50];
    char soyisim[50];
    int numara;
    float vizeNotu;
    
};

void main(){
    
    struct Ogrenci *geciciOgrenci;
    float ortalamaNot = 30;
    int i;
    char isim[50];
    char soyisim[50];
    int numara;
    float vizeNot;
    
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        geciciOgrenci = malloc(sizeof(struct Ogrenci));
        printf("Ismi girin: ");
        scanf("%s",isim);
        printf("Soyisim girin: ");
        scanf("%s",soyisim);
        strcpy(geciciOgrenci->isim,isim);   
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code allocates memory, and stores its address in `geciciOgrenci`. That works for the first element, however from the second element onwards, the new address allocated overwrites the previous one. Make the following changes.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Ogrenci{
    
    char isim[50];
    char soyisim[50];
    int numara;
    float vizeNotu;
    
};

void main(){
    
    struct Ogrenci *geciciOgrenci[5]; //declare array of pointers
    float ortalamaNot = 30;
    int i;
    char isim[50];
    char soyisim[50];
    int numara;
    float vizeNot;
    
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        geciciOgrenci[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Ogrenci)); // store the address in the ith element
        printf("Ismi girin: ");
        scanf("%s",isim);
        printf("Soyisim girin: ");
        scanf("%s",soyisim);
        strcpy(geciciOgrenci[i]->isim,isim); // refer to the ith element   
    }    
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("%s \n", geciciOgrenci[i]->isim); // access the elements
    }
    
}
```